# summation NCn-2x for x in range 0 to k/2

Tags: dynamic-programming, combinatorics

What is the efficient way to find summation of NCk-2x for x in range 0 to k/2?

I tried using naive approach but the complexity is very high. Is there any other approach for constraints N,k<100000.

I got this(https://oeis.org/A008949 )but still I'am unable to figure out something to calculate upto 100000 with O(n) or o(nlogn) complexity.

Comment: Please add specifications to your question, such as language, and maybe your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: @thesecretmaster I solved it using Dynamic programming in c++.Its working fine for smaller values , but 2-D array of size 100000 isn't possible.So I.am searching for some other approach

Comment: Got this formula from your link: T(n, 0) = 1, T(n, n) = 2^n, T(n, k) = T(n-1, k-1)+T(n-1, k). I guess you are taking about space complexity, But you only need n & n-1. Why not create array of size [2][K] and take [1][k] if n is even & [0][k] if it is odd. If you paste your solution somewhere and give me link, I can probably explain more.

Comment: @thesecretmaster He's talking about general approach. It is a computer science assignment, not a "write some code" one.

Comment: @pirate I tried what you said but still getting TLE. May be O(logn) is required. Or some formula.

Comment: I was talking about space complexity. Please share your code through http://pastebin.com/ or similar site.